# How to decode mp3 file

Tags: lisp, mp3, common-lisp, id3

how get the artist of a mp3 file using lisp

```
(let ((in (open "test.mp3" :direction 
        :input 
        :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
 (when in
   (loop for line =  (read-byte 'utf-8 in)

      while line do (format t "~a" line ))
    (close in)))
```

Comment: you should either use a simpler programming language for this task or, if your goal is to learn Lisp, use a simpler task. An introduction would be for example Practical Common Lisp, written by Peter Seibel.

Comment: http://gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-an-id3-parser.html

Comment: @larsmans: that is an answer, not a comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

A complete ID3 (MP3 tag) parser is described in the book [Practical Common Lisp, chapter 25](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-an-id3-parser.html).